# How to download with UWP webview by post requests?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms

How to download with UWP webview by post requests without using URI?
Most answers I have found is by downloading a file if you have the URI but what if the file is generated based on the post request? How can I download the file then? I am using Xamarin.Forms WebView and ExportRenderer.

Comment: I think you can post it and then get the html to download. To download that you can use background download.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the download URL with [XLabs HybridWebView](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView).

In the `OnPageFinisihed` method, you can catch the URL.

Comment: The URL is not enough. Is it possible to fetch the post data before sending it to the server. OnPageFinisihed is not good it will "generate" two downloads.